# Mean distance of objects of specific size in a given volume of space - visualization of planetary systems in the universe

Tags: density, observable-universe, exoplanets

This has been answered in this forum before in some ways I realize, but I have a rusty ability in calculus so was unable to make use of formulas!. Would love the help! I have been talking to my 11 year old niece about the probability of ever contacting another intelligent civilization...a thorny topic in any case...I posited that we shrink the AGE of the universe from 13.5 B years down to a mere 30 days. Came up with a factor of 1.67 x 10^11 [(13.5x10^9 x 365)/30]. If we use that same factor to 'shrink' the SIZE of the 'visible' universe to it's corresponding manageable size we get:
8.8 x 10^24 meters/1.67 x 10^11 = 5.27 x 10^13 meters which is around 350 AU's!! 3 times the distance to the edge of the heliosphere! A typical planet (as we have observed so far - 'heavy' earths around twice our diameter) would be the size of a plant cell or .015 mm. Now let's allow a 'typical' advanced civilization to be in a technologically advanced state for, say, a VERY generous 10,000 years...it would correspond to about 2 seconds in our 30 days of age of the universe scenario. But we need to get a sense of the distance between them on our scale of 350AU's being the size of the universe. Would be great to know for various estimations of the number of advanced civilizations we expect to find - scattered throughout the universe...(Drake equation studiously avoided)
My question (FINALLY!) - what would be the average distance between these plant cell sized *dots* (planets) be in our 350AU sized universe if there were, say, 10^10th, or 10^20th such planets? 0r 10^30th? etc. evenly distributed throughout the universe. Sorry for the long post...thank you for taking a stab at it!
PS. To sum up this crude visualization: Tiny tiny cell-sized *planets* pop up all over this massively *imagined* universe for 2 seconds at a time over the month the universe has existed. They are about ______km apart from each other. How likely is it that they would exist at the same exact 2 second pffffft of time **AND** be anywhere near enough to be able to detect each other?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, nobody knows how many intelligent civilizations are out there.

In the last decade or so, people have found evidence that planets orbit other stars. Before that, it was reasonable to suppose they did. But nobody know how many, or anything about them. Now we are finding that stars with planets are more common that stars without.

The easiest planets to find are "Hot Jupiters", planets totally unsuited to life because they are giant balls of gas that orbit closer to their star than Mercury.

More recently, more or less Earth sized planets have been found about the right distance from stars to have temperatures that might support life. We don't have firm ideas about how common those planets are.

We don't have any evidence that those planets have other conditions needed for life. Perhaps the James Webb telescope will find some of that evidence.

It is another leap from there to actually having life, and quite another to having intelligent life.

Ask again in a decade or so and you might get a better answer.

Comment: Absolutely. I was making a HUGE assumption that..."OK, let's say that there MIGHT be other intelligences out there"...and trying to explain that even if there were - the likelihood of them arising at the same precise time as our span of existence AND being in any kind of vicinity that would allow us to become aware of them is insanely remote.